# If Hamiltonian is not the total energy, then what to take as $H$ operator in Schrodinger's equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

A particle is confined to move in a circle, and the circle if rotating about its diameter with a constant $\omega$. In this case, I can find the total energy (say, $H_e$), which is the kinetic energy. Again I can find the Hamiltonian (say $H_h$) by first finding the Lagrangian.
Now if I want to write the Schrodinger's equation $H\psi=Ε\psi$,$ H_e$ or $H_h$ what should I write in place of $H$? And what would$ E$ mean? (Energy eigenvalue?) !
Edit:
[Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCVCm.jpg)

Comment: The energy is only kinetic energy in this case. Right? Therefore, the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian should be the same. Right? @Siddartha

Comment: Why would you write anything other than the actual Hamiltonian in the Schrödinger equation? In classical Hamiltonian mechanics, would you wroie anything other than the actual Hamiltonian in Hamilton's equations of motion?

Comment: @SRS Here the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian are not same. I have used H = p*θ' - L ( here θ' is the time derivative of the gen coordinate θ and p is the conjugate momentum.

Comment: @ACuriousMind So far I have used the equation Hψ=Eψ to find energy eigenstates and energy eigen values. Now if the Hamiltonian  is not the total energy then what will I get by solving the eqn?

Comment: @Siddhartha Please show your calculation where you prove that H is not same as L. In any case, you should use the Hamiltonian.

Comment: I believe that what the OP means is that, because of the constraint, the system is not natural so the Hamiltonian is conserved but is not the total energy of the systems, i.e. $H\ne T+V$.   If this is right then Dirac looked into this in his *Lectures on quantum mechanics*.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket

Comment: @SRS I have posted the calculation by a pic. Sorry, I could not type math notations.

Comment: @Siddhartha Are you using $L=\frac{1}{2} m(\dot{r}^2+r^2 \dot{\theta}^2)$? Isn't $r=a$? Do I misunderstand something?